# How to Implement Non-endpoint API Functions?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

This is a pretty high level question but I have been unable to find anything that explains it elsewhere:

I have a django class-based view with endpoints (GET, POST) but I have another method that's not an endpoint but I would like to include as it's used in the GET/POST methods. What would be the best practice for implementing this?

For example:

```
class users(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        # get method
        helperFunction()

    def post(self, request):
        # post method
        helperFunction()

    def helperFunction():
        # not an endpoint
```

Would this be the right way to do something like this? Should helperFunction() be standalone function outside of a class? Or should non-endpoint methods be in a separate class?

Apologies for the lack of specificity.

Comment: Why wouldn't you include it in the class, if it's used in the view? View classes already contain lots of related methods, eg `get_context_data`, `get_object`, etc.

Comment: As mentioned by Daniel, it would be smart to ask your self what sort of tasks this helper should perform. If it's not allready (or exactly how you like it) in the related methods, you could overwrite one of these methods to fit your needs.

Comment: I'll need to use this function in other places, so I'm confused about where to put it. I'm new to object oriented programming so it's breaking my brain a little lol

Answer (score 1):

pick the location based on the data the function uses.

1. If it should **process data** that is relevant only for the **class 
   instance**, then yes it belongs to the class
2. If it should **process data** that is **class type specific**, add it as a static method in the class, and feed it with the
   concrete    instance you need to be processed
3. If it should **process data** that is common for a **set of
   classes**, they you can either create an abstract class, put it
   there and inherit all classes that use the function from it, or make
   it external(see last option)
4. If it has a **general purpose**- *like time formatting for example*, throw it in the global space. Now ideally you would like
   to have a separate file where all shit piles, it makes the code base
   easier to maintain. In reality however it may be better to keep it
   in the file where your class is(provided the other classes that use
   it are in the same file)